# Restricting file upload size and file type in JSF primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

We are developing a forms page which contains two text box and one upload file option and when user fill info , upload file and click submit button .Form info should reach bean class and it reaches fine 
But iam  keeping Restricting file upload size it not works and how to keep restriction for file type as well .Please help me
Thanks in advance

versions

java 1.8

tomcat 8.5

primefaces 5.5

jsf-impl 2.2.4

jsf-api 2.2.4

Eclipse oxygen

Below is my JSF

```
<p:outputLabel  value="Contact Reference No.: * " escape="true" />
                <p:inputText value="#{user.contactref}" requiredMessage="#{error['form.contactrefrence']}" autocomplete="off" required="true"  />

                 <p:outputLabel  value="Error message *" escape="true"  />
                 <p:inputText  value="#{user.errormsg}"  requiredMessage="#{error['form.errormessage']}" autocomplete="off" required="true"  />



                 <p:outputLabel value="Attach a File:" escape="true" />
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{user.uploadedFile}"  dragDropSupport="false"  mode="simple"
        sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="5"  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt)$/" styleClass="attachment" />
        <br/>




                <p:commandButton  ajax="false" value="Submit"  actionListener="#{user.submit}"
                  escape="true"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to PrimeFaces 6.2 this issue has been fixed:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3290

When using "simple" mode before PF 6.2 the sizeLimit was not checked.